# AWS API Gateway Query parameter validation

Tags: api, aws-api-gateway

I have been trying to validate my request parameters using x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator, but unfortunately it is not working. Below is swagger file-

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "API Gateway - Request Validation Demo"
  },
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators" : {
    "full" : {
      "validateRequestBody" : true,
      "validateRequestParameters" : true
    },
    "body-only" : {
      "validateRequestBody" : true,
      "validateRequestParameters" : false
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator" : "full",
  "paths": {
    "/orders": {
      "post": {
        "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator": "body-only",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "CreateOrders",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CreateOrders"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
            }
          },
          "400" : {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseTemplates": {
                "application/json": "{\"message\" : \"Orders successfully created\"}"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "passthroughBehavior": "never",
          "type": "mock"
        }
      },
      "get": {
      "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator": "full",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "Account-Id",
            "required": true
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "type",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/InputOrders"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200" : {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Orders"
            }
          },
          "400" : {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseTemplates": {
                "application/json": "[{\"order-id\" : \"qrx987\",\n   \"type\" : \"STOCK\",\n   \"symbol\" : \"AMZN\",\n   \"shares\" : 100,\n   \"time\" : \"1488217405\",\n   \"state\" : \"COMPLETED\"\n},\n{\n   \"order-id\" : \"foo123\",\n   \"type\" : \"STOCK\",\n   \"symbol\" : \"BA\",\n   \"shares\" : 100,\n   \"time\" : \"1488213043\",\n   \"state\" : \"COMPLETED\"\n}\n]"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "passthroughBehavior": "never",
          "type": "mock"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "CreateOrders": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "Create Orders Schema",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems" : 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/Order"
      }
    },
    "Orders" : {
      "type": "array",
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "Get Orders Schema",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "order_id": { "type": "string" },
          "time" : { "type": "string" },
          "state" : {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "PENDING",
              "COMPLETED"
            ]
          },
          "order" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Order"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Order" : {
      "type": "object",
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "Schema for a single Order",
      "required": [
        "account-id",
        "type",
        "symbol",
        "shares",
        "details"
      ],
      "properties" : {
        "account-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{6}"
        },
        "type": {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [
            "STOCK",
            "BOND",
            "CASH"]
        },
        "symbol" : {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 4
        },
        "shares": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 1,
          "maximum": 1000
        },
        "details": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "limit"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "limit": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "InputOrder" : {
      "type": "object",
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "title": "Schema for a Input Order",
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "properties" : {
        "type": {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [
            "STOCK",
            "BOND",
            "CASH"]
        }
      }
    },
    "Message": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to validate my request parameters against some regex and enum values.

I am not sure if this is even possible or not. Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For HTTP parameter validation, API Gateway only supports marking one as 'required'. It does not support regex/enum values for parameters.

Comment: Yes, I got to know after reading lots of stuff. Thank you very much for summarizing that.

Comment: Does it still hold true? or do we have any option to sanitize the inputs parameter? like checking for regex

Comment: I am just playing with it, and it seems that it still only the required: true/false, and the rest seems to be ignored.